# What command is being sent when I execute a single line of a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on a project where I need to be able to understand some of the low-level details of Jupyter Notebook as a way of improving our existing application. In particular, it would be very useful if I knew the commands that the web-client was sending through the socket to the kernel.

For example, if I have a normal file "hello.py" that has one line

```
print ('hello world')
```

I am able to execute that file in the terminal by typing "python3 hello.py". If I have a Jupyter Notebook "hello.ipynb" that has the same content, in order to execute this I have to go into Jupyter Notebook and click run in order to get the output.

Basically, I wanted to know if there is a command-line-equivalent of the Jupyter Notebook version that is being run behind the scenes. It is important because our application basically intercepts the original system call and then records it, before allowing the system call to go on as usual.

i.e.

```
MYPROCESS python3 hello.py
```

vs.

```
python3 hello.py
```

MYPROCESS command-line currently works for regular .py scripts but not sure how to do it for jupyter-notebooks (since I don't know the command-line equivalent), and additionally, I would like to execute only the first N lines of the jupyter notebook as opposed to executing the entire thing.

I've read through the [Jupyter Client Communication](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/client.html) documentation, but was still confused about how to answer my question, especially since they don't provide many examples.

Comment: Do you have experience with interactive `ipython` sessions, either in shell window, or the `qt` version?  It may be easier to see points of correspondence between an interactive session and a notebook session, that with a stand alone script.  Executing a cell in a Notebook is like executing a block of code in an interactive session.  The cell content is sent as a JSON string from browser to server, and then translated into Python commands for the kernel.  The operating sysem (command-line) is not involved (except when starting the jupyter server).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Just to clarify, based off this answer it would not be possible for me to do what I was originally intending? My source of confusion is basically the difference between the communication of the regular python file and the kernel vs. the communication of the jupyter notebook and the kernel?

Comment: In normal script case, the OS starts a Python interpreter and gives it the commandline.  The interpreter reads the script named in the commandline, interprets it and executes it.